# how to add hyperlink to stack panel in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have binded value from web service using c# and my xaml code looks like as below

```
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="PhoneList" Height="532" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <Image Height="100" Margin="5" Stretch="Fill" Width="100"  Source="{Binding blogImage}"></Image>
     <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="20,0,0,0"  Width="300" >
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" LineHeight=" 24" MaxHeight=" 48"LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" Grid.Row="0" Foreground="Black" FontStyle="Normal" Text="{Binding blogTitle }" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Margin="0,3,0,0" Foreground="BlueViolet" FontStyle="Italic" Text="{Binding blogPostedon }" />

      </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
```

How can I add hyperlink to the entire stack panel and my hyperlink value is in data binding

Comment: You want to add for StackPanel or TextBlock? your question title says TextBlock

Comment: Wrap the required StackPanel or TextBlock inside "HyperlinkButton.Content"

Comment: @sanjeetharan:sorry i need for stack panel only edited...

Comment: @bit tag is not accepted while wrapping around stack panel

Comment: See the exmaple in my answer

Comment: How about add an OnClick handler to every object in your stackpanel that launches the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example

```
<HyperLinkButton>
    <HyperLinkButton.Content>
        <StackPanel>
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </HyperLinkButton.Content>
</HyperLinkButton>
```

Comment: after adding all my list values are hidden

Answer (score 0):

[`HyperLinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) only supports Text.

```
<HyperlinkButton>
    Hello World
</HyperlinkButton>
```

But you can do like this, set a Control template and enter the XAML you mentioned above inside

```
  <HyperlinkButton>
    <HyperlinkButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="PhoneList" Height="532" Background="{x:Null}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            .....
        </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
      </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </HyperlinkButton.Template>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: x:key is not available

Comment: @user2992174 ok check the modified answer